# Multiple paths in requirejs r.js optimize

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, r.js

Is there a way to keep one paths.js file to keep track of all paths for

```
//i know you can do this where configobject.paths = require('paths');
requirejs.config(configobject)

//and r.js build config
({
     paths:require('paths'),
})
```

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to achieve? Having one place to store all paths?

Comment: r.js builds all the modules in one file.  i have several files that are configured on app-init i would like to keep all of these paths in one module so that they can be referenced in only one place.

Comment: This is definitely annoying but r.js accepts a json file and require expects js so there's no js-only way to include a file in both. In addition the paths might (depending on where you run r.js from) have different prefixes. What I did was create a very simple powershell template that will auto-generate both my build.config and main.js files on build.

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to centralize my AMD module paths. This is an implementation in curl, but the same approach works for RequireJS:

Basically, but the config in a file:
https://github.com/SimpleAsCouldBe/appCore/blob/master/shared/appCore/setCurlPaths.js

And use the config in any page you want:
https://github.com/SimpleAsCouldBe/appCore/blob/master/exampleApp1/index.html

You can optimize this with grunt concat or something during the build. You can also tell grunt's requirejs optimizer about this shared config file:

```
# https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js
requirejs:
  oneForAll:
    options:
      mainConfigFile: "shared/appCore/requireConfig.js"
```